# Can Spring Data Elastic Search connect to a proxy REST service that connects to Elastic Search?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

My company has Elastic Search behind the REST endpoints /search and /count, but it hides the cluster nodes from access.

I could call those REST endpoints through Native DSL queries, but I don't want to create a lot of the boilerplate code that comes with creating queries and mapping responses, which is why I would like to use Spring Data Elastic Search to do a lot of that for me. I would like to know if it is possible to connect to Spring Data Elastic Search to an ES instance through a proxy REST endpoint, but based on the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients), it seems like Spring Data ES can only connect to the ES Instance. Has anyone else had this kind of need?

> Spring Data Elasticsearch operates upon an Elasticsearch client that is connected to a single Elasticsearch node or a cluster.

Answer (score 2):

You link to the [documentation, Chapter Elasticsearch Clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients). In this chapter, in the [section Client Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration) you find the description how to configure a proxy:

```java
ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
  .connectedTo("localhost:9200", "localhost:9291")                      
  .withProxy("localhost:8888")                                          
  .build();
```